# When and how did Luke Cage own his bar?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, luke-cage, luke-cage-2016

I recently watched Jessica Jones S1, followed by Luke Cage S1.  Through the first few episodes of Luke Cage various comments implied a specific series of events:

- Luke is Framed
- Luke goes to Prison
- > Luke meets his wife, Reva
- > Luke becomes enhanced and breaks out of prison
- > Luke begins working under the table at two jobs; it's stated this is because he can't make enough money working 'outside the system'
- Season one begins

I assumed Luke Cage S1 worked as a lead up to where Luke was when we meet him in Jessica Jones, but a few comments come up implying the Jessica Jones arc is in the past, and 2/3 of the way through LC S1

> We meet the doctor from Jessica Jones who references the events of Jessica Jones, thus implying that Luke running his bar is in the past.
>  We know that Luke was enhanced when he ran his bar so it must have happened after he left prison.  However, we also know that between leaving prison and LC S1 beginning Luke was too poor to afford a run-down apartment, let alone a bar, due to his fugitive status.  Further adding to this confusion, Luke confirms Jessica's guesses that the bar has a lot of meaning for him which implies he has had the bar for a long time.

When and how did Luke come to own his bar?  If it was before prison, how was he enhanced in Jessica Jones?  If it was after prison, how could he afford it, or how could he not afford to pay his rent in Luke Cage S1?

Comment: I seem to recall him owning it with Reva, with it technically probably being in her name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Luke obtained his pub (probably) sometime after escaping his prison, before meeting Jessica.

First lets get the watching order in place: "Luke Cage" is third in chronological order in the MCU, after "Daredevil Season 1" and "Jessica Jones".

Now lets get things in chronological order:

1. Luke is a policeman in Savannah, Georgia. He gets sentenced to prison for a crime he didn't commit.
2. Luke meets Reva, a counselor in the Seagate prison. She and Luke are starting to fall in love.
3. Luke starts fighting in the illegal fighting ring inside the prison. He ends up badly beaten up.
4. Luke partakes in procedure that gives him superhuman strength and bulletproof skin.
5. Luke escapes the prison, he joins Reva and they move to New York. At some stage they get married - **this is probably the time frame when Luke obtains the bar (probably on Reva's name, since he is still a fugitive).**
6. (Here is when Jessica Jones starts) Reva dies, seemingly in a bus accident.
7. Luke meets Jessica, they start dating after a while
8. ...most of "Jessica Jones" passes here. To avoid spoilers I'll just say that Luke's pub has been burnt down.
9. "Jessica Jones" series ends, some time later  Luke starts working at Pop's place - here is where the "Luke Cage" series starts.

Points 1-5 we can see in the flashbacks in the "Luke Cage" series, 5-8 you can watch in "Jessica Jones".

Comment: Thank you.  I hadn't considered the extra financial security and flexibility that his marriage provided.  That explains how he could afford a bar at that point, but be unable to make ends meet after Reva's death.  Do we know why it's made clear in Jessica Jones that the bar has so much sentimental value to him if he just recently bought it?

Comment: I'm fairly sure that he mentions that the bar was also important for his late wife. Also, with Reva gone it was the only joy in his life.